# Deserialize to class

Tags: vb.net, uwp

I have a class Person which I can serialize with the following code, but I can’t figure out how to deserialize the file back to the class.
I would be grateful for help on this. Thank you.

```
Imports Newtonsoft.Json
Imports Windows.Storage
Imports Windows.Storage.Streams

Public Class Person
   Public Property Name As String
   Public Property Age As Integer
   Public Property Gender As String
End Class

Public NotInheritable Class MainPage
Inherits Page
Private p As Person
Private pList As New List(Of Person)

Private Async Sub Save()
    Dim jsonContents As String = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(pList)
    Dim localFolder As StorageFolder = ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder
    Dim textFile As StorageFile = Await localFolder.CreateFileAsync("a.txt", CreationCollisionOption.ReplaceExisting)
    Using textStream As IRandomAccessStream = Await textFile.OpenAsync(FileAccessMode.ReadWrite)

        Using textWriter As New DataWriter(textStream)
            textWriter.WriteString(jsonContents)
            Await textWriter.StoreAsync()
        End Using
    End Using
End Sub
End Class
```

I tried the following but it doesn’t work.

```
    Private Async Sub GetData()
    Dim localFolder As StorageFolder = ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder
    Dim textFile = Await localFolder.GetFileAsync("a.txt")
    Dim readFile = Await FileIO.ReadTextAsync(textFile)

    Dim obj As RootObject = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(Of RootObject)(readFile) 
   End Sub
   Public Class RootObject
          'Public Property pList1() As List(Of Person)
      Public Property Name() As String
      Public Property Age() As Integer
      Public Property Gender() As String
   End Class
```

Comment: Please define "doesn't work".

Comment: Person and RootObject are not the same. You should start by making them the same.

Comment: Oh, I see it now.  I think your problem is that you are serializing a list of people, but you are deserializing to a single person.  If you change it to `Dim obj() As RootObject = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(Of RootObject())(readFile)`, it'll probably work

Comment: Hi Steven,
Thank you for your help. Your suggestion helped on the crash but my class is still empty. Obj() is though  filled with the data from the file. What is the correct way to fill my class with the data?
Debug.WriteLine(obj(0).Name shows the name of the firstperson
Like this ?
        For Each pers In obj
            p = New Person With {.Name = pers.Name, .Age = pers.Age, .Gender = pers.Gender}
            pList.Add(p)
        Next

Comment: Do you have to use it? eg instead of creating a class then calling it with JSON.Person, you could do it another way with no class and calling it with JSON("Person")

Comment: And as people already said, there is a difference when deserializing [x],[y],[z] and {x},{y},{z}, you should probably include a sample of your JSON

Comment: OK here is a sample of my JSON file, but the class and sample file is just a simple sample to learn how to do it.
[{"Name":"Henrik","Age":54,"Gender":"Mand"},{"Name":"Lone","Age":50,"Gender":"Kvinde"},{"Name":"Niels","Age":24,"Gender":"Mand"},{"Name":"Pernille","Age":26,"Gender":"Kvinde"}]

Comment: @henrikl2000 How is this issue going?

Answer (score 0):

You should make sure your VB class object's property in accordance with the **JSON key** or **JSON name**.

For example using your sample JSON data in your comment:

Since your JSON data is not complete, I modify it as the following:

```
{"pList1":[{"Name":"Henrik","Age":54,"Gender":"Mand"},{"Name":"Lone","Age":50,"Gender":"Kvinde"},{"Name":"Niels","Age":24,"Gender":"Mand"},{"Name":"Pernille","Age":26,"Gender":"Kvinde"}]}
```

You can keep the above Json data in a file named **my.txt**, if you want to deserialize the Json data to VB object, your VB objects classes should be as the following two classes:

```
Public Class Person
    Public Property Name As String
    Public Property Age As Integer
    Public Property Gender As String
End Class

Public Class RootObject
    Public Property pList1() As List(Of Person)
End Class
```

Please pay attention to that: the `pList1` property of `RootObject` class is corresponding to the **pList1** key or name in the JSON data.

Then you should be able to use the `JsonConvert` class to deserialize to `RootObject`.

```
Private Async Sub GetData()
    Dim localFolder As StorageFolder = ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder
    Dim textFile = Await localFolder.GetFileAsync("my.txt")
    Dim readFile = Await FileIO.ReadTextAsync(textFile)
    Dim obj As RootObject = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(Of RootObject)(readFile)
End Sub
```

Comment: Sorry  for the late reply . Thank you all for your help on this. Problem solved